Issue with setting rel Attribute for Links in Quill Editor
I’m facing a problem with configuring the Quill editor on my website.
I have a website built with PHP and Bootstrap. The site uses the Quill editor for content editing. I need the links inserted into the editor to have the rel="dofollow" attribute for administrators, while for regular users, the attribute should remain as is (e.g., rel="noreferrer noopener").
Here’s the code I’m using to initialize the Quill editor and handle links:
function quillINT(ct) {
    var quill = new Quill('#editor' + ct, {
        theme: 'snow',
        modules: {
            toolbar: toolbarOptions,
        },
    });

    // This section handles link processing
    quill.getModule('toolbar').addHandler('link', function(value) {
        if (value) {
            const href = prompt('Enter the URL');
            quill.format('link', href);
        } else {
            quill.format('link', false);
        }
    });
}

Problem: I need to modify this code so that:
For administrators using the editor, the rel="dofollow" attribute is added to all links. For regular users, nothing changes and links remain with their default attributes (rel="noreferrer noopener").
Challenges I’m facing:
How to properly implement a check to determine if the current user is an administrator or a regular user. How to correctly add the rel="dofollow" attribute to links in Quill.
Additional Information:
My code uses the quillINT(ct) function to initialize the editor. I also use the isAdmin variable to determine if the user is an administrator.
I haven't tried it yet, I want to know the best way to do it.
